# Check if a number is +-Inf or NaN

Tags: c

For the robustness reason, I want check if a float number is IEEE-754  +-Inf or  IEEE-754  Nan. My code is in the following, I want know if it is correct:

```
 #define PLUS_INFINITE          (1.0f/0.0f)
 #define MINUS_INFINITE         (-1.0f/0.0f)
 #define NAN                    (0.0f/0.0f)

 float Local_Var;
 /*F is a float numnber.*/
 if((unsigned long)(F) == 0x7f800000ul)
   {
    Local_Var = PLUS_INFINITE;
   }
 elseif((unsigned long)(F) == 0xff800000ul)
   {
    Local_Var = MINUS_INFINITE;
   }
   /*fraction = anything except all 0 bits (since all 0 bits represents infinity).*/
 elseif((((unsigned long)(F) & 0x007ffffful) != 0ul )
         &&((unsigned long)(F) == 0x7f800000ul))
        || 
        (((unsigned long)(F) & 0x807ffffful) != 0ul )
        &&
        ((unsigned long)(F) == 0xff800000ul))
   {
    Local_Var = NAN; 
   }
   else{}
```

Comment: As of C99, `<math.h>` has the functions (or macros) `isnan(x)`, `isfinite(x)`, `isinf(x)` and `isnormal(x)`.

Comment: I develop a code for embedded systems, and using the standard library like math.h is not permitted.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on this question. Seems well-researched and well-posed to me.

Comment: a NaN is not equal to anything, not even itself. so one way is `f!=f`

Comment: 1) "using the standard library like math.h is not permitted" critical restrictions like this belong in the post.  2) Disagree with the "code for embedded systems" --> "math.h is not permitted" rational as it is only the functions in <math.h> that incur an issue.  Constants & marcos are not a problem.

Comment: Is the `isfinite(x)` in your `<math.h>` a macro that you can simply copy?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

C99 has macros for the classification of floating-point numbers:

`fpclassify(x)` returns one of:

- `FP_NAN`: `x` is not a number;
- `FP_INFINITE`: `x` is plus or minus infinite;
- `FP_ZERO`: `x` is zero;
- `FP_SUBNORMAL`: `x` is too small to be represented in normalized format or
- `FP_NORMAL`: normal floating-point number, i.e. none of the above.

There are also shortcuts that check for one of these classes, which return non-zero if `x` is what :

```
   isfinite(x)
   isnormal(x)
   isnan(x)
   isinf(x)
```

The argument `x` can be any floating-point expression; the macros detect the type of the argument and work for `float` and `double`.

**EDIT**: Since you don't want to use (or cannot use) `<math.h>`, you could use other properties of nan and inf to classify your numers:

- `nan` compares false to all numbers, including to itself;
- `inf` is greater than `FLT_MAX`;
- `-inf` is smaller than `-FLT_MAX`.

So:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main()
{
    float f[] = {
        0.0, 1.0, FLT_MAX, 0.0 / 0.0, 1.0/0.0, -1.0/0.0
    };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        float x = f[i];

        int is_nan = (x != x);
        int is_inf = (x < -FLT_MAX || x > FLT_MAX);

        printf("%20g%4d%4d\n", x, is_nan, is_inf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this solution, you must adapt the limits if you want to use `double`.

Comment: Is "`nan` compares false to all numbers, including to itself;"  a result of the IEEE-754 spec, C spec or both?

Comment: The C standard doesn't require that a floating-point implementation have nans. I think `nan != nan` is a property of IEEE-754 floats, but that's not authoritative.

Comment: Although `x != x` is a _good_ and the right idea, embedded systems are known for using "parts" of IEEE-754 - lacking full compliance.  AFAIK, OP is using `IEEE-754` _formatted_ data, but code's implementation of  `IEEE-754` _functionality_ may be weak.

Comment: @chux: I'm not familiar with development on embedded systems. The original question doesn't mention any particular restrictions on IEEE-754.

Comment: [Is it safe to assume floating point is represented using IEEE754 floats in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31973105/2410359) is a good ref.  The core issue is OP says "robustness", "IEEE-754", "embedded", "math.h is not permitted" and posts incorrect and non-portable code.  There is so much in conflict amongst these 5, that I doubt even a good answer like yours will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Casting floats to longs like that is wrong. It should be either a union, or a type-punned pointer.

Here's a working example from dietlibc (with doubles):
https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/lib/__isinf.c
https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/lib/__isnan.c

Musl has a shorter fpclassify, and also proper constants for floats:
http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/math/__fpclassifyf.c

Comment: Downvoted: Pointer type punning breaks strict aliasing rules and is UB.

Comment: @user694733: yes, but type punning is what the OP obviously had in mind. This answer says why it didn't work.

Comment: @MOehm Type punning with union is fine, assuming that one is using compiler that supports C standard which is new enough. Suggesting to use pointers to do type punning is *never* correct.

Comment: @user694733 Concerning "type punning is _never_ correct"  What is wrong with type punning `int i = foo(); unsigned u = *((unsigned *) &i);`?

Comment: @chux Problem is the lack of guarantees. Compiler optimizer could legally break your code. And there is always work-around, in this case: `unsigned u = i;`.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use the `fpclassify()` functions of [@M Oehm answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36150774/2410359)

Alternatives:

```
float F;
if (F <= FLT_MAX) {
  if (F >= -FLT_MAX) {
    puts("Finite");
  } else {
    puts("-Infinity");
  }
} else {
  if (F > 0) {
    puts("+Infinity");
  } else {
    puts("NaN");
  }
}
```

If code wants to mess with the bits and assuming `float` are in [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) format:

```
assert(sizeof (float) == sizeof (uint32_t));
union {
  float f;
  uint32_t u32;
} x;
x.f = F;
```

Masks depend on relative endian of `float` and `uint32_t` endian.  They usually are the same.

```
// Is F one of the 3 special: +inf, -inf, NaN?
if (x.u32 & 0x7F800000 == 0x7F800000) {
  if (x.u32 & 0x007FFFFF) {
    puts("NaN");
  } else if (x.u32 & 0x80000000) {
    puts("-Inf");
  } else {
    puts("+Inf");
  }
}
```