# How does the gcc compiler store 32 bit floating point numbers?

Tags: c

I'd like to know how the gcc compiler stores the float 32-bit type. Does it store it like in the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int sign : 1;
    unsigned int fraction: 23;
    unsigned int exponent: 8;

} floatS;
```

Comment: [Is it safe to assume floating point is represented using IEEE754 floats in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967040/is-it-safe-to-assume-floating-point-is-represented-using-ieee754-floats-in-c)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: Given that bit-fields are completely implementation-defined, nobody knows how the one you posted is laid out in memory.

Comment: Your CPU  floating point hardware determines the layout.

Answer (score 1):

According to [section 4.15 of the GCC 13.2 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Architecture-implementation.html), the encoding of `float` objects is determined by the target platform ABI and not GCC.

I am not sure I entirely believe that without seeing details of how GCC adapts to the ABI. Nonetheless, in practice, you will almost always see IEEE-754 binary32 used for `float`, with one bit for the sign, eight for the exponent encoding, and 23 for the primary significand encoding.

Further, they will be in that order (pending resolution of byte ordering in memory) and not in the order listed in your question. So, even aside from implementation-dependent issues of bit-fields, the structure you show in the question will not match a `float`.